# How to share data across two data centers?

Tags: web-server, database, datacenter

Let say I have 2 data centers in 2 different cities. Datacenter A to serve city A, and datacenter B to serve city B. How do I achieve the following scenarios:

1. Redirect users in each city to respective datacenter. City A to Datacenter A, and likewise with city B.
2. Any changes to the data in any of the Datacenter should be reflected to the other datacenter.
3. In an event of downtime in one of the datacenter, traffic to the problematic dataserver should be redirected to the other datacenter.

The above is for a website with database, using Microsoft technologies (server and database).

Comment: This will probably be voted to close in its current form.  It's too vague.  You should probably expound on your question in terms of what kind of connectivity you have between them, what your RPO/RTO needs to be, specific apps, etc.

Comment: This is incredibly open ended. There are hundreds of ways to do each component of this, and there are hundred of available free design examples available via Google-fu. We're here for technical configuration issues, not architecting an entire solution. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Do you have your own IP space? Do you run your own network? Is there private interconnections between the datacenters? What data needs to be replicated?

Comment: This is way too open-ended as is -- the answer you got is the best you can expect.  If you can ask a more specific question we might be able to give you better/more helpful answers though :-)

Answer (score 5):

1. Geolocation
2. You don't say what type of data but database boxes can be clustered/mirrored, filesystems can be synced/rsynced, VMs can be replicated - there's a solution for everything but we'd need some/more information.
3. Multi-site load-balancing will sort this for you, I use Cisco GSS's but there are other opions.

Basically you can do this, it's not 5 minutes of work but it's not rocket engineering either, it's unlikely to be free but either way you'll need to know and explain a LOT more about the specifics of your requirements.